# Setting "this" equal to an existing object in a constructor

Tags: c#

A kind of weird question, but I'm hoping there's something out there that will help shorten the process or else I'll have to do it many many times for each project.

We've made a shift toward MVC in our office and so we're now building "Entity classes" for all of our objects.  In order to enforce certain levels of reusability, I've separated the core functions of the Entity from the database but this presents a particular issue with my constructors.  The way I've written the DAL piece is as a stand-alone static class (to also help hide it from the outside world) that just returns the objects I need ... but then I have to basically copy those fields back into the class via the constructor and I'm hoping for a better way.

```
public class MyObj{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }


    public MyObj(int prmId){
         List<MyObj> raw = DAL.get(prmId);

         if(raw.Count != 1)
             throw new Exception("Invalid number of objects returned");

         ID = raw[0].ID;
         Name = raw[0].Name;
         IsActive = raw[0].IsActive;
         CreateDate = raw[0].CreateDate;
    }


    static class DAL {
         public static List<MyObj> get(int? prmId){ 
             // database stuff to call a Stored Procedure and return 0 or more MyObjs
         }
    }
}
```

Where I'm doing all the copying from raw[0], is there some way of basically saying "this = raw[0]" ?

I'm doing this same structure in a number of Entities, so any shortcut would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling the DAL inside the constructor in the first place? A better approach would be to have whoever creates an instance of `MyObj` just call `DAL.get().FirstOrDefault()` or something similar. There's no need to create another instance of an object if you already have an instance of it!

Comment: you could use [automapper](http://automapper.org/) for that, it's easy to use and flexible

Comment: @PoweredByOrange or provide a static GetInstance(int id) or similar would work too, course that doesnt really address OP concerns

Comment: You cant assign to 'this' in c#.  You could work out something using reflection though, or a third part lib like automapper

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Mostly, Separation of Concerns.  We don't want the DAL being called by the front-end.  We want to make it go through the class itself so that any validation can be done before the DAL is hit.

Comment: @cavillac That's fair, however, it seems like the logic can still be in a method that does the validation and calls the DAL (this is what the "Business" or "Mid" layer is used for) rather than the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have made some architectural mistakes:

The first one is that a domain model entity must not know how it must be saved / loaded. So you've broken the Single Responsibility Principle.You must have a repository or some other pattern over them that handles persistance logic.

The second mistake is that generally speaking you've introduced a concrete dependency into your domain model entity ( the DAL class is seen as the concrete type in your domain model entity). This is bad habbit and you just violated the inversion of control principle and the general spoken "code over abstraction and not on concrete implementations" rule.

Comment: Do you have any actual suggestions as opposed to just throwing out terminologies?  All the knowledge in the world is useless if not used to actually help people.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static **GetObject** instead assgin all properties in constructor.

```
public class MyObj{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public static MyObj GetObject(int prmId){
     var obj = DAL.get(prmId).FirstOrDefault();
     return obj != null ? obj : new MyObj();
    }
}


static class DAL {
     public static List<MyObj> get(int? prmId){ 
         // database stuff to call a Stored Procedure and return 0 or more MyObjs
     }
}
```

Comment: I dont know that this address the OP concerns.  Seems like he is trying to avoid the left right copying, which, using a static method wont prevent

Comment: Yes, one of the chief developer's primary desire is to have people using constructors as much as possible and only use a static method when returning more than one object.  I used to use a more "pure static" approach but now need to figure out a clean approach that works within a constructor.